# Using a folder shortcut in environment variables

Tags: windows, environment-variables, visual-studio

I want to know if it's possible to use a folder shortcut as an enviroment variable element.

I'm using a specific folder layout to organize my programming libraries, similar to the OSX Frameworks layout:

```
Library root ->  
   Versions ->  
      1.0 ->  
         Include  
         Lib  
      2.0 ->  
         Include  
         Lib  
   Include (shortcut to one of the Includes in Versions)  
   Lib (shortcut to one of the Lib ins Versions)
```

This way I can specify a default version, but I'm also able to use any other versions.
My problem is that Visual Studio doesn't link my projects if I use the shortcuts for the LIB environment variable, but it works if I use the original folder.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Please edit your question to explain what you want a little more clearly. Perhaps with an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hmm, are you perhaps looking for something like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `LIBPATH` for windows?

Comment: @Nifle: My problem was about using folder shortcuts (an Explorer feature) in a environment variable (I use the LIB variable for D language libraries). The solution is using a symlink or junction instead of a folder shortcut (check grawity's answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that shortcuts are not a system-wide feature – they get special treatment only inside the Explorer shell. Usage "in environment variables" is irrelevant here.

Instead of shortcuts, you can use junctions or symlinks through `mklink` – both work at filesystem level and will be supported by all programs.

Comment: A folder shortcut, AKA Hardlink, AKA junction. If I wasn't out of 24hr votes, I'd vote this. .  Gotta bookmark for later.

Comment: @surfasb: Except folder shortcuts are *not* hardlinks, which are *not* symlinks, which are *not* junctions. They are four separate functions.

Comment: Ack, I was thinking a (common noun) shortcut to a folder, not (proper noun)Shortcut to a folder.